# How to insert text in a cell in Google Sheets through Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'll start by saying what I wanna achieve. I want to have some sort of button on google sheets that when clicked creates a template of whatever I put in. This template is a table complete with cell borders, text and formulas and colours

I discovered that I can do something similar to that by assigning a script to an image in google sheets which when clicked will run the script. Problem is I haven't figured out a way to add text into a google sheets cell through running the script.

I also don't know how to modify cell colour and cell border through the script so if there's a way for that please let me know.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And, can you provide your current script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I'll reiterate. I want to have some sort of button on google sheets that when clicked creates a template of whatever I put in. I discovered that I can do something similar to that by assigning a script to an image which when clicked will run the script.

The template that I want to insert into the script of the "button" is a table complete with cell borders, text and formulas. So, I want my script to be able to add text into a cell in google sheets. So far I haven't found a function that does that.

If you also found a way to modify cell borders through the script then that'll help too.

Comment: 'Whatever I put in' is not an adequate explanation. Please consider examples.

Comment: I haven't been on the website but from what I recall of the policy of the website is that this is not a coding service, it's meant to solve specific problems that you have with your code. In that sense we would need what is the input you give your code, what is the expected output and a sample of the code you wrote so far, clearly indicating what is it that you can't solve. In general I would recommend you just follow the Google Documentation you can access right there from the script editor. Click the `?` at the top right and go to training or documentation, Google has a good set of documents

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment seems like you are looking for generic advice on how to write code. I would say this is not quite the forum for that and more for solving specific issues with your existing code.

I recommend following goole scripts documentation. You can start off with https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-2#0 which should get you started and then head on over to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet and see what functions on what types of objects are available to you.

In general you will be using functions like `.setValue()` or `.setValues()` to set the text in specific cells. This is done on a `range` class that you would typically get from a `Sheet` class. So for example if I wanted to set the text value to `Test` in the cell A1 I could do this with either of the following 2 lines:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue('Test');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).setValue('Test');
```

Both lines do the same, just the way you indicate where you want to set values differs. As an example of how good the Google refference is you can find the details on `.getRange()` here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column

Similarly there are functions to set the borders as well as any other formatting you like. Do keep in mind that it's not ideal to code everything you want to set, so you might want to look at creating a template spreadsheet and then copying everything from it with that button instead.

Comment: Yeah im a complete beginner and dont really know what this website's for. I'll look into the resources you gave me thank you very much